# Проблема с установкой пакетов в Atom

Tags: kali-linux, atom

Недавно начал изучать линукс, через терминал на kali linux скачал атом и попытался установить компилятор c++. В итоге получаю ошибку, которая на фото. Как решить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Например, сменить редактор на другой? Поддержка Atom прекращена больше года назад